# Zathura not opening hyperlinks

Tags: hyperref, viewers

I am using neovim with zathura as my LaTeX editor. I am using the hyperref and URL packages to insert a link to a website. I know zathura has recognised the hyperlink because it places a box around it (see below). However, clicking on this link does not open the corresponding page unless a firefox window is already open, in which case it opens a new tab with the corresponding URL. Can anyone explain this unusual behaviour?

Note: I am running the Pop!_OS 20.04 (ubuntu based) distro.
[image: zathura highlights links]

Comment: Does not seem to have something to do with LaTeX or `hyperref`. Seems like a viewer or system problem. Try another third-party viewer, try `xpdf`, try Acrobat (which behaves differently from everything else).

Comment: Related: [Error when excecuting firejail from zathura: cannot create /run/firejail/profile/14844 - Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/620912/error-when-excecuting-firejail-from-zathura-cannot-create-run-firejail-profile/670651#670651)

Answer (score 4):

I think the problem is that Zathura sandboxes the process, which disable the feature to create a sandbox (and browsers need that feature).

To fix the issue (as far as I know) there are 2 ways

1. Disable Zathura's sandbox. Add this

   ```
   set sandbox none
   ```

   in zathurarc file (usually in `~/.config/zathura/zathurarc`). See [`man zathurarc`](https://man.archlinux.org/man/zathurarc.5) for possible options.

   Note that setting the option by typing `set sandbox none` in Zathura's command line may not work.
2. Disable browser's sandbox.

   Zathura uses xdg-open to open the URL. So you would need to modify xdg-open's settings.

   A simple way to test executing commands in Zathura is `exec firefox` (or similar).

   For Firefox use

   ```bash
   env MOZ_DISABLE_CONTENT_SANDBOX=1 firefox
   ```

   Source: https://wiki.mozilla.org/Sandbox

   ---

   Related: if you use Chrome instead, it will raise the error

   ```
   ERROR:nacl_fork_delegate_linux.cc(323)] Bad NaCl helper startup ack (0 bytes)
   ```

   In that case

   ```bash
   google-chrome-stable --no-sandbox
   ```

   works. (source: https://superuser.com/questions/971922/google-chrome-on-a-fresh-centos-7-1-not-starting-up)